# How to remove byte to byte delay using MCP2210

Tags: spi, microchip, usb-device

I am using a Microchip MCP2210 USB to SPI converter, however during operation, there is a delay between the sent bytes. Is there a way to remove this ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what that delay is, but page 38 of the datasheet (https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22288A.pdf) has settable parameters at offsets 16-19 that may resolve your issues.

[image: from data sheet page 38]

A quick scan of the data sheet shows four or five High Byte/Low Byte pairs for registers with the label "Delay Between Subsequent Data Bytes".  You should check them all.

Comment: I guess 17 should say "(high byte)".

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yes

Comment: Those bits are already set for no delay. The delay that I am experiencing is that of about 12ms. Thanks

Comment: @Chris how big a packet have you defined?

Comment: For that matter, how do you know about the timing of the usb output?  Are you measuring it on the USB host side?

Comment: I defined a packet of 4000 bytes (for reading an EEPROM). I am seeing the delays when probing the SPI clock on the SPI side.

Comment: There are a few registers with the same name.  Keep searching.  Also, have you actually read the settings?  Experience tells me that there's sometimes a difference between believing your procedure to set the registers worked, and knowing they've worked!

Comment: @Chris But have you probed the USB side? It may well be that the host driver is dawdling a bit.